# How to automate oauth flow to retrieve credentials?

Tags: python, oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm creating a python script which calls the google analytics api to get some real time data and later store it in database. But before calling the api I have to get the oauth token.

This is what I've so far which involves a little manual labor by clicking on the link, getting the verification code, and then pasting it in the console like such:

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(o['installed']['client_id'], o['installed']['client_secret'], ga_real_scope, o['installed']['redirect_uris'][0])
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print ('Go to the following link in your browser: {0}'.format(authorize_url))
code = input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
```

Is there a way to automate this without using something like Selenium?

Comment: Sounds like you want to go the route of a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount). See this [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py) for an example of how to do it.